# How to convert timestamp to seconds in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery Legacy Sql, we use timestamp_to_sec() function to convert timestamp to seconds. What is its equivalent in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

BigQuery Legacy SQL

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT UNIX_SECONDS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
```

Comment: Documentation link for `UNIX_SECONDS` for the sake of posterity: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#unix_seconds